# how to joing two tables and get the values to an array in cakephp controller and passed that value to view?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

here is my sql query

```
SELECT order_finalizeds.order_entry_headers_id, order_finalizeds.finalized_state
FROM order_finalizeds
INNER JOIN fabric_orderings
ON order_finalizeds.order_entry_headers_id=fabric_orderings.order_entry_headers_id;
```

how to get this value to and array and passed it to view?

Comment: You can execute custom query, but it is always better to follow the cakephp rules. Please read this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html if you have any doubt after this, post a message.

Comment: Have you read the official docs on retrieving data in CakePHP? This is a relatively simple case that is well explained in the official docs. What version of CakePHP are you using? You need to provide more information in your question like the relevant model associations. As it stands it looks like you've made no effort to solve this problem yourself!

Comment: yes i did though its bit of complex to me but some how i resolved this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply execute the custom query with

```
$result = $this->Modal->query('your sql query');
```

And for the passing that value in view file you can use set() like:

```
$this->set('result', $result);
```

now you can access result variable in the view file.

Comment: does this similar to an array?

Comment: and how do you iterate through list of values?

Comment: A custom query really shouldn't be used for this query as it should be done using a contain or by defining the join in a `find()`. The OP hasn't provided enough details to properly answer this question yet!